# Координаты Барабана JS

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function rotate(time) {
  var secs = time,
    mills = time * 1000,
    interval;
  interval = setInterval(function() {
    deg = -mills / 2;
    if (deg > 360) deg -= 360;
    document.querySelector('.game-roulette-numbers').style = 'transition: none; transform: rotate(' + deg + 'deg);';
    mills -= 10;
    if (mills == 0) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, 10);
}
```

```css
.game-roulette-numbers {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/b2Uj84T.png);
  width: 339px;
  height: 339px;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  z-index: 2;
  margin-top: 1px;
  margin-left: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="game-roulette-numbers" style="transition: none; transform: rotate(0deg);"></div>
```

Есть такой код. Вызывается он так - rotate(5) - барабан будет крутиться 5 сек.
Как поменять значения deg?
Если менять mills, то получается фиг пойми что (анимация у барабана сразу увеличивается, и с ним происходит что-то не то.)

В чем суть. Как например сделать так чтобы при завершении координаты барабана были например: 25deg.

Answer (score 2):

**колесо фортуны** ... выигрышное число внизу диска

```js
function timer(a) {
  return {
    play: function(c) {
      var d = performance.now();
      c = c || a.to;
      requestAnimationFrame(function e(b) {
        b = (b - d) / a.duration;
        1 <= b && (b = 1);
        a.elem.style.transform = "rotate(" + (a.from + (c - a.from) * b | 0) % 360 + "deg)";
        1 == b && a.callback && a.callback();
        1 > b && requestAnimationFrame(e)
      })
    }
  }
};
var div = document.querySelector('.game-roulette-numbers'),
  but = document.querySelector('#go'),
  num = 0;
anim = timer({
  from: 0,
  to: 360 * 3 + 120,
  duration: 2 * 1000,
  elem: div,
  callback: function() {
    alert(num)
  }
});


but.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
  var n = (15 * Math.random() | 0);
  num = [4, 10, 3, 9, 2, 8, 1, 0, 14, 7, 13, 6, 12, 5, 11][n];
  anim.play(360 * 3 + n * 24) //задать нужный угол поворота
});
```

```css
.game-roulette-numbers {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/b2Uj84T.png);
  width: 339px;
  height: 339px;
}
```

```html
<div class="game-roulette-numbers"></div>
<input id="go" name="" type="button" value="go">
```